# My Function Doesn't Know My Struct Values (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function, struct, undefined

I'm new to doing structs, so please bear with me if this turns out to be a dumb question. I have one header file and four .cpp files that all include it. I have a struct called ToDoLista and it has string nameIt and int DeadLine. Then I have the things whose type name I don't know that are like, the Soccer and DropOffMax and stuff.

```
ToDoLista Soccer, DropOffMax, CookDinner;
Soccer.DeadLine=6;
Soccer.nameIt="SOCCER";

//and so on, for a total of six, 3 ints and 3 strings definitions.
```

This struct seems to be finnicky if I try to move it around because if it's in the header it's included three times and it wont run due to 'multiply defined' whatever. If I put it in one of my three non-main cpp files, it seems that the struct won't work because some of it has to be defined in main(). So now it's in my main cpp file, but I have functions that use these values, and those functions are in my non-main cpp files, which as far as I know compile before the main one. To get around that, I put the struct declaration in the header, and the definitions in my main (I may have mis-worded that) AND THEN I say 'okay, run the function 'CheckItTwice'.

```
//MAIN
Soccer.DeadLine=6;
//and so on for all six, like before.

//ok, NOW run the fx.
CheckItTwice(Soccer.Deadline, Soccer.nameIt);
```

The issue here is that if I tell CheckItTwice to say, cout the string, or the int, it runs the program without errors, but returns nothing in the console where the cout should be, because apparently they haven't been defined yet, as far as the function is concerned. Why is this/do you know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Define the struct in your header and `#include` that header in the cpp files. In the header try adding

```
#pragma once
```

at the top of your header file. This is a Microsoft specific extension - documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4141z1cx.aspx)

The more portable version is to add

```
#ifndef _SOME_DEF_
#define _SOME_DEF_

struct ToDoLista { 
    string namit;
    string project;
    int status;
    int speed;
    int difficulty;
    int priority;
    int deadline;
}

#endif // _SOME_DEF_
```

Be sure to remove struct definition from the .cpp file.

Comment: Nope. Nothing changed. Buncha red lines under everything so it looks like it wont compile (but it does) and that's the only difference

Comment: `#ifndef LETSDOTHIS
#define LETSDOTHIS
struct ToDoLista{
 string namit;
 string project;
 int status;
 int speed;
 int difficulty;
 int priority;
 int deadline;
#endif   } Pushups, ClipNails, Shampoo, Soccer, Pocket, DropOffMax, Laundry, HomeSchool, Portfolio;
`   this wont work, it says they're already defined in my main file. am i doin it wrong?         OH wait hold on i need to move the bracket...

Comment: No, it went from 59 errors (mostly multiply-defined ones) to 58. :(

Comment: Error 53 error LNK2005: "struct ToDoLista Shampoo" (?Shampoo@@3UToDoLista@@A) already defined in Dyno 1.1.obj C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Dyno 1.0\Dyno 1.0\ToDo.obj

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the "defined multiply" errors you need to define your struct in a header file, and put a `#pragma once` or `#ifndef...etc` block at the top.  See [this here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7877/)

Include the header file in any implementation (cpp) file you plan to use the struct in.

The line

```
ToDoLista Soccer, DropOffMax, CookDinner;
```

declares three instances of the struct `ToDolista`, called `Soccer`, `DropOffMax`, and `CookDinner`.  They are *not* types, they are instances *of* a type, that type being `ToDolista`.

I can't comment on the contents of `CheckItTwice()` as you didn't provide them, but [look here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/) for guidance on using cout.  You might want to consider passing the struct as one argument to this method, preferrably as a const reference.

Comment: I can use cout just fine, and proof that the issue is specifically the definition itself, is that CheckItTwice says to `cout << "it's " << Soccer.Deadline << "so hurry up" << endl;` and it shows up as "it's  so hurry up" in the console. So it's the variables themselves with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved using something I saw while searching desperately online: extern. it seems that if I put the declaraction in the header, the definition in a cpp, and then declare the object again in another cpp but with 'extern' before it, it works like a charm as far as keeping the values from the original definition.

Header.h

```
struct ToDoLista{
string namit;
string project;
int status;
int speed;
int difficulty;
int priority;
int deadline;

};
```

Side.cpp

```
ToDoLista Pushups, Tumblr, Laundry, CleanRoom, CleanHouse, Portfolio;

void CheckItTwice(int staytus, string name){
if(staytus==1){//not on the list
    staytus==2;
    cout << "hurry up and" << name << " okay?" << endl;
```

Main.cpp

```
extern ToDoLista Pushups, Tumblr, Laundry, CleanRoom, CleanHouse, Portfolio;

Pushups.namit = "Push Ups";
Pushups.status = 1;
Pushups.speed = 0;
Pushups.difficulty = 0;
Pushups.priority = 0;
Pushups.project = "Get Fit";
Pushups.deadline = 20131102;

CheckItTwice(Pushups.status,Pushups.namit);
```

This works for me, and I hope this 'answer' helps someone else.

Comment: Your answer at least clarifies your question, that being you wanted global variables visible across multiple implementation files.  The answer is - DON'T USE GLOBALS!!  You're using c++ now so if you must have "globals" of some kind then use a singleton pattern.